# How to plot data on map from XML?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-maps-markers

How do I plot data on Google Maps from XML?

Following picture is my XML format:

[image]

With this format I have to plot markers on Google Maps with following JavaScript code:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

/* var customLabel = 
        Sports: {
            label: 'S'
        },

        Education: {
            label: 'E'
        },
        Crime: {
            label: 'C'
        },
        Health: {
            label: 'H'
        }
  };*/


  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 42.129220, lng: -80.085060},
      zoom: 15
    });
     var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});


    /*if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Your Location Found.');
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }*/
   downloadUrl("x.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('title');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          /* var short_description = markerElem.getAttribute('short_description');
            var news_url = markerElem.getAttribute('news_url');
             var news_date = markerElem.getAttribute('news_date');*/    
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('categories');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);

          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,

          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
      });




}


  /*function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  }*/



function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}

</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= key_num &callback=initMap">
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting output. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code?

Comment: in downloadUrl("x.php", function(data) { my file x.php is unable to call from directory. What's the reason behind it ?

Comment: is there any  problem in my xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

Will be better if you put the error message of console, but the first  I see is that there isn't the API_KEY, you can get it here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=ES

Also when you post a code try to delete the code commented.

Comment: i have api key but i didnt post it and i am not getting output of map . There is no error message.

Comment: and  the commented code is working but i want to run code which is not commented.

Comment: It's difficult figure out when it hasn't error messages or an animate code as "jsfiddle" to test, but maybe can be because in the code lack put the marker in the map with: `marker.setMap(map);`

Comment: in downloadUrl("x.php", function(data) { my file x.php is unable to call from directory. What's the reason behind it ?